# disable caching ImageUtils.loadTexture

Tags: javascript, three.js

I download a texture generated at the same address and with some GET parameters. Due to this following download does not occur but is taken from the cache. Added random GET parameter type rnd = Mat h.random (), is now re-load a texture. But it turns out that the previous texture still in memory and they're not needed. How does disable the cache for certain textures?